# Updating checkbox From custom buttons

Tags: custom-button, field-update

I have tried so many times for the checkbox to be updated to true when a file is uploaded, however, despite trying and also searching on google, I still couldn't change the checkbox value.. Is there anything wrong with the codes?

```
 if({!Account.Check__c } == false)
     {
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Account");
          c.id = "{!Account.Id}";
          c.Check__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]); }
```

Comment: When adding JavaScript to a page you should always have your browser's JavaScript console displayed. This will report errors that are otherwise hidden. In Chrome you display that via View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the required scripts at the start of the button?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js")}
```

Comment: Do I have to include both?